# Avoid the nested IF in AutoIt

Tags: if-statement, nested, autoit

Below is my AutoIt code. I want to reduce this code and avoid putting a lot of "If ... Else ... EndIf" constructs in my function.

How can I do that?

```
Func launchTestsCC($partenaire, $projet)
    If $CometEnv = "DEV" Or $CometEnv = "VAL" Then
        initDossierFormConfig($partenaire)
        initPartenaireWin($partenaire)
        Sleep(500)
        For $i = 2 To 8 Step 1
            $ouvrirDossier = ouvrirDossier($configDossier[2], $configDossier[3], "ADI,C", $configDossier[4], $configDossier[5], False)
            ConsoleWrite("$ouvrirDossier ==> " & $ouvrirDossier & @CRLF)
            If $ouvrirDossier = 1 Then
                Sleep(1000)
                jabSetCombo("", "FRAIS MEDICAUX", 3)
                jabSetCombo("", $listsContrats[$i], 4)
                ConsoleWrite("$listsContrats[" & $i & "] ==> " & $listsContrats[$i] & @CRLF)
                jabSetText("", $currentDate, 5)
                jabSetCombo("", $configDossier[6], 5)
                jabSetCombo("", $configDossier[7], 6)
                jabSetText("", "19549", 7)
                $valider = jabClicBouton("Valider")
                If $valider = 1 Then
                    If getWinError() = 1 Then
                        ConsoleWrite("getWinError() $valider ==> 1" & @CRLF)
                        setTestResult($openSheet, $CalcResult, $partenaire, $listsContrats[$i], "Dossier créer", "TEST OK")
                        $benef = jabClicBouton("ADI,FM,B")
                        If $benef = 1 Then
                            If getWinError() = 1 Then
                                $ajouter = jabClicBouton("Ajouter")
                                $searchTextbenef = searchTextInPageTimeOut("jabGetLabel", "Appliquer à :", 5)
                                If $ajouter = 1 And $searchTextbenef = 1 Then
                                    selectCheckBox("", 3)
                                    $x4 = 0
                                    $y4 = 0
                                    $checkBoxS3P3 = rechercheImage("Benef_S3P3.bmp", 5, 1, $x4, $y4, "")
                                    If $checkBoxS3P3 = 1 Then
                                        $codeRetour = cliqueSur("Benef_S3P3.bmp", -65, 0)
                                        If $codeRetour = 0 Then
                                            ConsoleWrite("Erreur en séléctionant S3P3" & @CR)
                                            setTestResult($openSheet, $CalcResult, $partenaire, $listsContrats[$i], "Erreur en séléctionant S3P3", "TEST KO")
                                        Else
                                            $valider = jabClicBouton("Valider")
                                            If $valider = 1 Then
                                                If getWinError() = 1 Then
                                                    $retour = jabClicBouton("Retour")
                                                EndIf
                                            EndIf
                                        EndIf
                                    EndIf
                                Else
                                    setTestResult($openSheet, $CalcResult, $partenaire, $listsContrats[$i], "Probleme au clic sur ajouter benef", "TEST OK")
                                EndIf
                            Else
                                ConsoleWrite("getWinError() $benef ==> 0" & @CRLF)
                                setTestResult($openSheet, $CalcResult, $partenaire, $listsContrats[$i], "Impossible d'ajouter des bénéf", "TEST KO")
                                ContinueLoop
                            EndIf
                        EndIf
                    Else
                        ConsoleWrite("getWinError() $valider ==> 0" & @CRLF)
                        $suiteConfig = "Cadence de recouvrement : " & $configDossier[8] & @CR & "Mode de recouvrement : " & $configDossier[9]
                        $disConfig = "Paramètres du dossier : " & $configDossier[2] & " | " & $configDossier[3] & " | " & $configDossier[4] & " | " & $configDossier[5] & @CR & $suiteConfig
                        setTestResult($openSheet, $CalcResult, $partenaire, $listsContrats[$i], "Message d'erreur ou Warning" & @CR & $disConfig, "TEST KO")
                    EndIf
                EndIf
            Else
                ConsoleWriteError("Erreur ouverture dossier " & $partenaire & @CRLF)
                $suiteConfig = "Cadence de recouvrement : " & $configDossier[8] & @CR & "Mode de recouvrement : " & $configDossier[9]
                $disConfig = "Paramètres du dossier : " & $configDossier[2] & " | " & $configDossier[3] & " | " & $configDossier[4] & " | " & $configDossier[5] & @CR & $suiteConfig
                setTestResult($openSheet, $CalcResult, $partenaire, $listsContrats[$i], "Erreur ouverture dossier/Temps dépassé pour ouvrir le dossier" & @CR & $disConfig, "TEST KO")
                ContinueLoop
            EndIf
        Next
    EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>launchTestsCC
```

Comment: Use a switch : https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/keywords/Switch.htm or a select: https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/keywords/Select.htm statement to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Something that might help you is making your *if statements* have multiple conditions instead of defining multiple if statements.  As said in the **AutoIt helpfile**:

> The expression can contain the boolean operators of AND, OR, or NOT as well as the logical operators <, <=, >, >=, =, ==, and <> grouped with parenthesis if needed.

Here's an example:

```
if $myValue = 1 AND $yourValue = 2 Then
    ...
EndIf
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate it into multiple function and call the first function, them in each function place a call to the next one. For example, if I want to create and decorate a window, the steps are:

```
- Create the window
- Decorate the window
```

You can write 2 functions corresponding to 2 steps and 1 function to hide your implementation like this (assume that `_CreateWindow` returns the handle to the created window or `Null` if can't create the window, `_DecorateWindow` returns boolean `True` if no error occur and `False` if can't decorate the window)

```
Func _createDecoratedWindow()
  Local $hwnd

  Switch _createDecoratedWindow__createWindow($hwnd)
  Case 'createWindow' ; A failure occurs at createWindow step
    ; Do something on failure, e.g: write an error message to log file
  Case 'decorateWindow' ; A failure occurs at decorateWindow step
    ; Code to execute when the step decorateWindow failed
  EndSwitch

  Return $hwnd
EndFunc

Func _createDecoratedWindow__createWindow(ByRef $hwnd)
  $hwnd = _CreateWindow(...)

  If $hwnd <> Null Then ; Check whether the operation is success
    ; Do something on success before proceed to the next step
    Return _createDecoratedWindow__decorateWindow($hwnd) ; Next step
  Else
    ; You can add some code to execute everytime the operation is failed here
    Return 'createWindow' ; Return name of the step at which the chain is broken
  EndIf
EndFunc

Func _createDecoratedWindow__decorateWindow(ByRef $hwnd)
  Local $decorateSuccess = _DecorateWindow($hwnd)

  If $decorateSuccess Then
    Return ; No error occur
  Else
    ; Do something when error occurs at this step
    Return 'decorateWindow'
  EndIf
EndFunc
```

You should get [the syntax highlighted code on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/3xugm8Mp) for easier reading.

Organize the code this way, the custom error handlers are grouped inside the `Switch` statement, and the default error handlers are put in the `Else` case of each step. Locating a specific handler is easy.

There's one more benefit, you can easily add a new step to the chain. For example, if I want to change the window size to 500x300 before decorating, I can write an extra step `_createDecoratedWindow__resizeWindow` like below (assume that `_SetWindowSize` returns `True` on success and `False` on failure):

```
Func _createDecoratedWindow__resizeWindow(ByRef $hwnd)
  If _SetWindowSize($hwnd, "500x300") Then
    ; Do something on success, if needed
    Return _createDecoratedWindow__decorateWindow($hwnd)
  Else
    ; Handle error here, if necessary
    Return 'resizeWindow'
  EndIf
EndFunc
```

and change the previous step to call this one instead of `_createDecoratedWindow__decorateWindow`

```
Func _createDecoratedWindow__createWindow(ByRef $hwnd)
  $hwnd = _CreateWindow(...)

  If $hwnd <> Null Then
    ; On success code
    ; Just change the line below and you're done
    Return _createDecoratedWindow__resizeWindow($hwnd)
  Else
    ; On failure code
    Return 'createWindow'
  EndIf
EndFunc
```

You can also add a new `Case` to the `Switch` statement if you need to handle error for this step.

However, this approach will make your parameter list grows quickly, since each steps must take arguments not only for itself but for *all* other steps. The result of the operation is another problem since the return value is used for error detecting. In the code above, I must use a `ByRef` parameter to transfer the result.

In short, each step is a function in the form

```
Func stepName(...)
  PerformTheOperation()

  If TheOperationIsSuccess() Then
    OnSuccess()
    Return NextStep() ; if any
  Else
    OnFailure()
    Return 'stepName'
  EndIf
EndFunc
```

Then write a wrapper

```
Func operationName(...)
  ...
  Switch CallTheFirstStep()
  Case 'firstStep'
    AdditionalActionsToHandleError()
    ...
  EndIf
  ...
EndFunc
```

Note: Function names in my example are all ugly to avoid name clash.